# Show all Org mode entries that contain a link to the current entry

Tags: org-mode

It's basically "What links here?".

Using [Org mode links](http://orgmode.org/manual/Handling-links.html), I'd like to be able to **get the list of headings which contain a link to a specific heading**.

Example file:

```
* Target
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID: 509039F8-5B43-4C9B-8FA3-F37E3A2EEC10
  :END:

* Heading containing link

  id:509039F8-5B43-4C9B-8FA3-F37E3A2EEC10

* Another heading containing the same link

  id:509039F8-5B43-4C9B-8FA3-F37E3A2EEC10
```

When the cursor is at `Target`, I'd like to get the list of all headings that link to it:

```
* Heading containing link
* Another heading containing the same link
```

Comment: This should be enough to get you started:  `(let ((id (org-entry-get (point) "ID")) result) (save-excursion (goto-char (point-min)) (while (re-search-forward (concat "id:" id) nil t) (push (org-get-heading) result)) result))`  You can look at `org-id-update-id-locations` to see how to get a listing of all files that may contain ID and you can loop through each file.  You can create a variation of `org-get-heading` if you need something a little different -- e.g., gather the stars, or use `match-string-no-properties` if the text properties are not to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach in a single file is below. It avoids the direct use of regular expressions.

```
(defun get-headings-with-links ()
  (let ((tid (org-id-get)))
    (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'link
      (lambda (link)
    (when (and (string= (org-element-property :type link) "id")
           (string= (org-element-property :path link) tid))
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (org-element-property :begin link))
        (org-get-heading)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up simply using:

```
(defun what-links-here ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((id (org-entry-get nil "ID")))
    (if (> (length id) 0)
        (org-search-view nil (concat "id:" id))
      (message "No ID - nothing can be linking here"))))
```

Comment: Result is exactly what I needed, but perhaps there's room for improvement.